# Authenticate Javascript Program for Gcloud AutoML Vision API

Tags: javascript, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-vision

I am currently working on a project whereby I have used gcloud automl to train an image classifier. I have got it working fine and it is able to handle my requests using access-tokens. However, my issue lies in that access-tokens only last for an hour. I would like to be able to create a method in my client-side javascript or another way to authenticate such that it is indefinite and I do not need to manually generate new tokens.

I have looked through the samples and docs on gcloud and found a sample that describes a possibility with the People API but I am not sure how to translate this to the Vision API.

Currently I am sending a request like the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/(project-id)/locations/us-central1/models/(model-id):predict",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "access-token"); 
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        processData: false,
        data: objString,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Cannot get data");
        }
    });
```

If there is a way to alter this method (or write a new one) to make a permanent token or another authentication form that is indefinite, then that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/before-you-begin) along with a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating_a_service_account). Depending on your OS, you could use it until you turn off your machine, or set it as a permanent environment variable.